# Facebook app infinite loop issue

Tags: php, facebook

My facebook app was working perfectly fine till this morning. The only change I made was that I changed the url to a local server. Later when I changed the url back to my deployment server, it gets stuck in an infinite loop with state and code variables constantly getting refreshed every second.

I then created another app on my deployment server and it is doing the same. Interestingly, the same code runs fine on my staging machine. My deployment server is from awardspace. Any idea what to do.

```
 require 'src/facebook.php';

 // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(

'appId'  => 'app id',

'secret' => 'secret',



));


   // Get User ID
   $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

if($user==725363641){

try {       
        echo "something" , "</br>";
} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    error_log($e);

    $user = null;

}


}// second if

else{

echo "You are not authorized to use this application", "<br/>";


}

}//outer if


// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.

if ($user) {

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

} else {

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>       'user_status,user_likes,manage_pages,publish_stream'));

}


    ?>


    <?php if ($user): ?>



  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a> or <a href = "menu.php">Return to    Main Page</a>
    ***<?php else: echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';       </script>";
    exit;***

   ?>

  <div>



    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:

    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>


  </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Here is the very basic code which isnt running. Actually I tested it again and the part in ** is giving the problem. IF i take it out I see my page and html being displayed but when i put it in this infinite loop problem occurs. However, putting it back or taking it out, nothing is making the app run properly

thanks.

Comment: I took out the major code and right now i want my code to print a single line !

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the facebook source file and use the [latest php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src) provided by facebook.

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work. As I said earlier that the same code with the same sdk is working on my testing server. And was working till last morning on the deployment server as well, suddenly giving me this issue. Any other idea? This project was supposed to be in production and I am already under pressure from the client..